# Sync DNS zones on a Standalone DNS server from a AD integrated zone

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, dns-zone

I need to install DNS services on a Server [which is a part of a domain but not a Domain Controller].
I have around 12 Domain Controllers which have DNS roles installed on them and they have around 25 AD integrated DNS zones.

I do not want this new server to be promoted to a domain controller but should have all the DNS zones replicated to them.

Could you please help me understand how I can do it without manually creating secondary zones on this server?

Thanks - Roshan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without manually creating secondary zones on this new server. These are the steps you need to follow:

You need to add this new server to the name servers tab for each zone you want it to hold a secondary copy of. Then you need to allow zone transfers for each zone to all servers listed on the name servers tab of the zone. Then you need to create each zone as a secondary zone on this new DNS server.